# Difference between import a module with and without ".js" in es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm recently learning chrome extension development, and find out that:
When I use

```
import { foo } from "./index"
```

in `background.js`, I will get an error: `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.`,
while using

```
import { foo } from "./index.js"
```

Everything just works properly.
Could someone please tell me the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 needs you to reference a file for it to fetch.

Extension-less or a directory to use index from are supported by external loaders such as webpack, with correct configurations.

With these, if you import without extension, it will look for an `index.js` inside your import path as if it were a folder.

Or If you have a folder `foo`, and inside it a file `index.js`, you can import `./foo` without the extension and it will import the index file.

Directly in ES6 as far as I'm aware (e.g. for Chrome browser direct interpretation without some loader), I believe a full file path is necessary for local imports, so you should include the `.js` extension when you want to import a specific file.